# Issue while processing data from LTSpice in Python

Tags: python

I use Python (3.9) for automatically generating a netlist for LTSpice. The part of creating the netlist and running the simulation works fine. When importing the simulation data from the created .raw-file, I encountered some weird issue I wasn't able to solve:

While plotting a signal in LTSPice (e.g., current through resistor R2) works just fine ([current vs time through a resistor in LTSpice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcQkM.png)), the same data seems to become a mess after importing it into Python (utilizing PyLTSpice, [LINK](https://pypi.org/project/PyLTSpice/), [same current plotted in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRejq.png)).
I tried to use another package for importing the data (ltspice, [LINK](https://pypi.org/project/ltspice/)), but still the same behavior.

As a voltage source I use a PWL-file (sine, amplitude=1V, f=50Hz), which seems to be a part of the problem. When I use a sine signal from LTSPice, and simulate some 10 signal periods, everything works out fine. However, what I want is to simulate just one signal period with a PWL-file (the now used sine is just for testing, this signal will be of arbitrary waveform in the future).

A workaround seems to be a combination of running LTSPice in 'ascii-mode' and utilization of the .save command. However, I want to avoid this solution since working with binary output seems more elegant to me..

Maybe someone could help! Thanks in advance!!